# How to Extract Number with single quote in excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, numbers

I am trying to extract length from a string of data. As the set of string I receive is not always the same, I am trying to find a way to extract data by finding the string that contains single or double quotes, because my most of my length dimension are either in ft or inches. But my code returns only the first number, 3 in this case. I don't know how to extract both 3 and 6 as separate outputs.
'''

```
data = "String-SomeString-3' 6"-AnotherStrng"

extract = Split(data, "-")

For i = 0 To UBound(extract)
    If InStr(extract(i), "'") > 0Then
        MsgBox val(extract(i))
    End If
Next i
```

'''

Comment: Try  `MsgBox extract(i)` ? `Val()` will cut the message short. "The Val function stops reading the string at the first character that it can't recognize as part of a number."

Comment: Also it would probably be `Data = "String-SomeString-3' 6""-AnotherStrng"` but I guess that's just an example that isn't being used really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. Just needed to follow through on your idea.

```
Sub Measure()

    Dim Data        As String
    Dim Extract()   As String
    Dim i           As Integer
    Dim Feet        As Integer
    Dim inch        As Integer

    Data = "String-SomeString-3' 6""""-AnotherStrng"

    Extract = Split(Data, "-")
    
    For i = 0 To UBound(Extract)
        If InStr(Extract(i), "'") > 0 Then
            Extract = Split(Extract(i), "'")
            If UBound(Extract) Then Feet = Val(Extract(0))
            inch = Val(Extract(UBound(Extract)))
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    MsgBox Feet & IIf(Feet = 1, " foot", " feet") & " and " & _
           inch & " inch" & IIf(inch = 1, ".", "es.")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Variatus. This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use regular expressions?

```
Option Explicit
Sub due()
 Const data As String = "String-SomeString-3' 6""-AnotherStrng"
 Dim RE As Object, MC As Object, M As Object
 Dim S As String
 
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "\d+(?=('|""))\1"
    If .test(data) = True Then
        Set MC = .Execute(data)
        For Each M In MC
            S = S & " " & M
        Next M
        Else: S = "no dimensions"
    End If
End With
MsgBox S
End Sub
```

[image]